# Isolate specific folders from updating on git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I'm not that experienced with version control and it's my first time with Git. We're using BitBucket and TortoiseGit, set it up and working.

Now, I would like to be able to isolate a folder (let's call it "resources") which will hold some resource files such as graphics, scripts, sounds which are not really crucial to the coders on the project. The coders must not be able to pull from or synch with this folder.

However, another team should be able to manipulate this "resources" folder and make changes to it, while also being able to receive the changes made by the coders.

I understand that there is an ignore function that creates a .gitignore list. But as I understand it, this list will ignore files/folders across all users so nobody will effectively be able to access the "resources" folder as soon at it's defined to be ignored.

Another way would be to branch the "origin" into a "coders" branch and "resources" branch. Then the "coders" would push and pull to/from remote "coders", push to (but never pull from) "origin" and also never push to "resources". "Resources" would always pull/push to and from "origin" but never to "coders".

I suspect this process would really need some kind of a "push to specific list of branches" option.

Not sure if I'm right about how this works, I have tried a couple of experiments but am obviously failing. Am I looking at it the wrong way? What would be the best solution for a situation like this (preferably using TortoiseGit).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't put too much (binary) "resources" in that folder: as a git repo, those resources will be cloned around, and they can increase the size of a repo significantly.

I would recommend isolating those in a separate repo, and declare that repo as a [**submodule**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) of your main development repo.

That ways, the coders can clone the main repo, and don't have to, if they don't need to, initialize and update the 'resources' submodule.
But if they need, then a `TortoiseGit > Submodule update` is enough for that content to be loaded in their working tree.

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too early.  Thanks for your answer @VonC.  So to be clear, I understand that cloning a repo locally would, well, clone it and thus take up space on a local HDD. But this shouldn't increase the size of the remote repo, right?  As for using submodules, when you mention a separate repo, this would actually mean that I need to assign a new repo on BitBucket for the submodule? I believe BitBucket offers one free repo so perhaps this is not the optimal solution for us right now. I'll look into this anyway though.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ichtyander you are cloning a remote repo locally, so the size is the same (on remote and on local). Plus, BitBucket let you have as many *public* repos as you want (only private ones are limited).

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks for clearing it up a bit, I appreciate it very much.